# Capture top command to file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, server

I want to capture the output of top to a file but there is a problem, the output is always the same. For example, the code below grabs the %CPU returned by the top command. The problem is that everytime I execute this code it shows the same %CPU usage, why?

```
top -n 1 | awk '/^%Cpu\(s\)/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: `%CPU` is calculated by subtracting the total CPU use between each iteration of the display, and dividing by the amount of time between the displays. It's not accurate on the first display, because there's no previous iteration to subtract.

Comment: Just run `top` normally, you'll probably notice that the first screen always display the same percentage, it doesn't get accurate until the second time. But `top -n 1` means you're only capturing that first screen.